# Как через Threading сделать запуск python скриптов?

Tags: python, многопоточность

Создал главный скрипт 'thread.py':

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.7
import threading
import time
import os

def script_1():
    print('запуск sceipt_1')
    os.system("/home/machin/scripts/script_1.py")

def script_2():
    print('запуск sceipt_2')
    os.system("/home/machin/scripts/script_2.py")

t = threading.Thread(target=script_1)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=script_2)

t.start()
t2.start()

print('main')
```

В script_1 и script_2 - цикл приветствия:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.7
import time

while True:
    print("Привет, я скрипт_1")
    time.sleep(1)
```

При запуске основного скрипта вывод корректен, но при завершении через Ctrl+z - процесс остается и его приходится выключать руками.

[image: первый скрипт]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

обавил аргументы "daemon=True" в главном файле:

```
t = threading.Thread(target=script_1, daemon=True)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=script_2, daemon=True)
```

Теперь, после запуска thread.py - его невозможно закрыть через Ctrl+Z и Ctrl+С тоже не останавливает работу! При этом создаются процессы с именами script_1 и script_2 a threads.py нету в процессах. Сам главный скрипт вроде как отрабатывает и закрывается, а дальше работают только запущенные из него скрипты (это видно на скриншоте)!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как настроить главный файл на запуск других python скриптов (скрипты должны работать в цикле), при нормальном закрытии файла (Ctrl+z) и удалением всех процессов при его закрытии?